# Aggregate hourly data for each month of the year

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, zoo

I've looked around for something similar, but couldn't find anything. I have an airport data set which looks something like this (I rounded the hours):

```
Date        Arrival_Time        Departure_Time        ...
2017-01-01  13:00               14:00                 ...
2017-01-01  16:00               17:00                 ...
2017-01-01  17:00               18:00                 ...
2017-01-01  11:00               12:00                 ...
```

The problem is that for some months, there isn't a flight for a specific time which means I have missing data for some hour. How can I extract hourly arrivals for each hour of every month so that there are no missing values?

I've tried using dplyr and doing the following:

```
arrivals <- allFlights %>% group_by(month(Date), Arrival_Time) %>%
                            summarise(n()) %>%
                            na.omit()
```

but the problem clearly arrises as group_by cannot fill in my missing data. I end up with data for every month, but not entries for some hour (e.g. no entry for month 1, hour 22:00).

I could currently get my answer by filtering out every month in its own list, and then fully merging them with a complete list of hours, but that's really slow as I have to do this 12 times. Ideally I'm trying to end up with something like this:

```
Hour    Month    January    February    March   ...   December
00:00     1        ###        ###        ###     ...    ###
01:00     1        ###        ###        ###     ...    ###
 ...
00:00     12       ###        ###        ###     ...    ###
23:00     12       ###        ###        ###     ...    ###
```

where ### is the number of flights for that hour of that month. Is there a nice way of doing this?

Note: I was thinking if I could somehow join every month's hours with my complete list of hours, and replace all na's with 0's, then that would work, but I couldn't figure out how to do it properly.

Hopefully the question makes sense. I'd gladly clarify if anything is unclear.

EDIT:
If you want to try it with the nycflights13 package, you could reproduce my attempt with the following code:

```
  allFlights <- nycflights13::flights

  allFlights$arr_time <- format(strptime(substr(as.POSIXct(sprintf("%04.0f", allFlights$arr_time), format="%H%M"), 12, 16), '%H:%M'), '%H:00')

  arrivals <- allFlights %>% filter(carrier == "MQ") %>% group_by(month, arr_time) %>% summarise(n()) %>% na.omit()
```

Notice how arrivals doesn't have anything for month 1, hour 02:00, 03:00, etc. What I'm trying to do is have this be a complete data set with the missing hours filled in as 0.

Comment: Can you reproduce your example using e.g. the nycflights13 package dataset? It will be easier to help you with a reproducible example.

Comment: Sure! I posted it as an edit above. You might need to install some packages to be able to use the conversion functions to convert the time though. I think lubridate?

Comment: I checked the arrivals data using your logic. And it seems no arrival time for "03:00","04:00","05:00".Do you still want these hours to appear even no observations there?

Comment: yes, I want them to appear with a count of 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the code below to generate what you need.

```
library(stringr)

dim_month_hour<-data.frame(expand.grid(hour=paste(str_pad(seq(0,23,1),2,"left","0"),"00",sep=":"),month=sort(unique(allFlights$month)),stringsAsFactors=F))

arrivals_full<-left_join(dim_month_hour,arrivals,by=c("hour"="arr_time","month"="month"))

arrivals_full[is.na(arrivals_full$`n()`),"n()"]<-0
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do? I'm not sure if I'm aggregating exactly how you want, but the !is.na should do what you're looking for.

```
arrivals <- allFlights %>% group_by(month(Date), Arrival_Time) %>%
            rowwise() %>%
            summarise(month = plyr::count(!is.na(Arrival_Time)))
```

Edit: I may not be clear. Do you want a zero to show for hours where there are no data?

So I'm circling it. There's a cool packaged, called `padr` that will "pad" the date/time entries with NAs for missing values. Because there is a `time_hour` field, you can use `pad`.

```
library(padr)
allFlightsPad <- allFlights %>% pad
```

Then you can summarize from there. See [this page](https://edwinth.github.io/blog/padr-intro/) for info.

Comment: Right, I'm trying to fill the data with a zero where it's missing. I tried what you said, but there seems to be an issue with the summarise? I get an error saying:

Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `month` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 2

Comment: Try it with the `rowwise()` line and see. To add a "dummy" value of zero for missing data, you could use `mutate` rather than `summarize`. Also, I second atiretoo for data.

Comment: Still can't seem to get it to work :\. I posted an edit with how to get a similar issue with the nycflights13 package dataset.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're trying to do. The issue is since those times don't exist in any table, you'll have to generate them somehow, then summarize. One potential solution would be to create an hour table with 00:00 through 23:00 in it, then summarize for those. I'm looking into something that's close. I'll edit this comment.

Comment: hmm... i ran it on the nycflights13 dataset. It added rows, but there still seems to be the same amount of missing data. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I tried summarise on both arr_time and using hour(hour_time). I'm still grouping by month and hour.

Comment: It'll just pad the time_hour field, so you'll have to fill the month and hour fields in using the time_hour field. Try the left_join that moisussi06 suggested.